# Setting multiple enum flags in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, enum-flags

Is there any way to set multiple enum flags (that are traditionally separated by | in codebehind) in XAML? I tried something like:

```
<ns:SomeControl Flags="FlagA|FlagB" />
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

WPF does support this through a type converter. It can be done by using a comma in between enum values:

```
<ns:SomeControl Flags="FlagA,FlagB" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the accepted answer code

```
<ns:SomeControl Flags="FlagA,FlagB" />
```

But you also need add a `TypeConverter` attribute on the property to make it work

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(EnumConverter))] //yeah, this line
Public MyEnum Flags
{ ...
```